# Refresh the page once using JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript

Can anyone help me with the script to refresh the page once .

I am already using `window.history.forward(1);`

but it gives me a wierd exception in the console .

```
`Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult:
"0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame ::
resource:///components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 457"  data: no]`
```

help me with different script to refresh a page.

Comment: yes ,  but i didnt get what i want .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `window.location.reload()`

Answer (score 3):

`location.reload(true)` ... come on man google that.